# Script causing 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php

My site has been suffering "500 Internal Server Error" often of late, and host has advised that this bundle.css.php script might be the reason why ...

```
<?php
ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
header('Content-Type: text/css');
$files = split(",",$_GET['files']);
foreach($files as $key=>$val){
    if(file_exists($val.'.css')){
        include_once($val.'.css');
    }else{
        echo "\n\n/*** File \"$val\" does not exist. ***/\n\n";
    }
}
?>
```

In the words of my host ...

"It is trying to buffer all of output into ob_gzhandler. It is taking a very insecure list of parameters passed in GET variable 'files', and is then trying to include those files into the output. I'm not sure exactly what list of parameters is being passed, but I suspect there is a bug somewhere in your scripts that is passing a large array of file names to this script, and thus trying to build a buffered object that is too large."

This is well beyond my expertise, so any advice to fix the problem would be much appreciated. Many thanks.

---

UPDATE

The error log is full of lines such as ...

[Mon Apr 23 15:44:41 2012] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (12)Cannot allocate memory: couldn't create child process: /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp for /home/xxxxxy/public_html/xxxx.php, referer: http://www.xxxxxxx.com/wp-content/themes/xxx/style.css

Comment: Does this functionality _always_ fail, or only sometimes when an unknown user is performing an unknown action?  Of the latter, you want to make your unknowns known.  Look into using some kind of logging framework or adding useful debugging output from the code so you can see more useful runtime information when an error occurs.  Specifically, you want to know what the value of `$_GET['files']` is when this code fails, as well as what the _actual_ error is (not just a user-facing 500 server error).

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Such is my inexperience that I don't know where to look.

Could anyone advise on where I might get useful debugging output, and how I would determine of the $_GET['files'] when the code fails? Server log?

Comment: There should definitely be a server log, and the hosting provider should be able to get you that information.  (Especially if they're even willing to look at your code for you.)  If they don't provide server log information, look for another provider :)  For creating custom debugging output, you would want to add stuff to the code for that.  This might be a good place to start looking for logging tools: http://stackoverflow.com/q/341154/328193

Comment: Cheers. Have written brief update to original post re: error logs.

Comment: Ok, the out of memory error helps a bit.  It's probably what the hosting provider suggests... The system is trying to build too much.  Since it's getting the values from the `$_GET` collection, the host logs may provide more information.  Can they get you the web server request log that corresponds with the error log?  That would tell you what the value of `$_GET['files']` was at the time.

Answer (score 0):

for this script to be a little saffer you should check if $_GET variable is set with the isset function, 2nd you should never give user access to the variables you are using, as it is easy to inject malicious code into it , if you can use $_POST instead or at least check if the values passed in the $_GET variable is alphanumeric.